# Who made Elros king of Númenor?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion, numenor

Elros, brother of Elrond, was crowned king of Númenor by who? The Valar? By the Edain? It's weird how he went from being raised by Maglor and Maedhros to becoming the first king of the most powerful nation of Men.

Comment: I would suspect that the vast majority of the Edain were recently slaves or refugees, not exactly a powerful nation.

Comment: when i said Most powerful Nation,i was referring to the later years of Numenor

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From *Akallabêth*, the fourth part of *The Silmarillion*:

> At the feet of the mountain were built the tombs of the Kings, and hard by upon a hill was Armenelos, fairest of cities, and there stood the tower and the citadel that was raised by Elros son of Eärendil, whom **the Valar appointed to be the first King of the Dúnedain**.

So the answer is **the Valar**. Whether it was any Vala in particular, Tolkien didn't say, but it seems likely that the appointment of Elros was decided by all of them together as a body.

Comment: Which, incidentally, is why the Stewards did not announce themselves as the kings of Gondor even a thousand years after Earnur disappeared: to do so would have been in defiance of the Valar themselves, since their kingship was (indirectly) divinely ordained.

Comment: On second thought, it may also be worth mentioning that Elros was the heir to the House of Hador (Earendil, Tuor, Huor, Galdor, Hador), the House of Beor (Elwing, Dior, Beren), and Haleth (through his great-great grandmother.) So he was also a completely natural choice: an heir to all three Houses of the Edain.